# How to enable ENUMs in Symfony 2 / Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

When running `doctrine:mapping:import` i get an error:

> Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

It seems I need to set `use_native_enum` to `true` some how. However, all documentation and blog posts are refering to Symfony < 1.4. Is there any what would be the solution in Symfony 2?

Comment: I think you'll find an answer to your question in the [MySQL Enums](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) cookbook article.

Comment: But where to put this code so it gets run when `doctrine:mapping:import` is started?

Comment: A little late but I think my answer is right for you @umpirsky

Answer (score 124):

For Symfony 2 projects, add this to the doctrine dbal configuration in `app/config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        mapping_types: 
            enum:       string
```

My full doctrine config looks like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
            set: string
            varbinary: string
            tinyblob: text

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

Code adapted from [here](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/09/deal-with-mysql-types-natively.html)

Then run:

`app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --dump-sql --ansi`

Comment: yes this works but issue i guess is it erases all the enum types from the database when you do a "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: Came across this issue with a Symfony 4 app using `doctrine:migrations:diff` and this answer still sorts it :-)

Comment: The strange thing that happened to me was that, the migration containing the `enum` was migrated successfully but i couldn't migrate any migration after that!

Comment: I am going to run this command `php bin/console make:migration` but it displaying error like:  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.

Comment: Worked fine for me, Thanks mate

Answer (score -1):

Considering the Doctrine cookbook only provides partial answers as to how to make enums interpret as strings, the following should work regardless of how Doctrine is configured.

The error points you at the name of the file: `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform`.php - in there, you'll find that the default list is embedded in the function `initializeDoctrineTypeMappings` as follows:

```php
$this->doctrineTypeMapping = array(
            'tinyint'       => 'boolean',
            'smallint'      => 'smallint',
            'mediumint'     => 'integer',
            'int'           => 'integer',
            (...)
```

Adding simple enum support for all doctrine users, regardless of the rest of the setup, is simply achieved by extending the list with:

```
'enum' => 'string'
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to change the code from "third" parties. When you want to update this code (which you want: new features, security etc.) your changes will also be replaced.