# Doctrine2 workaround for mapping MySql 'bit' data type

Tags: mysql, mapping, doctrine-orm

I have a few columns in my database schema that have bit data types and am having problems with Doctrine2 mapping it. I keep getting:

> Unknown database type bit requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

Is there any work around? I was thinking of just changing the data type to boolean and just use true and false statements but that would mean changing the schema on a large scale which I dont have time for.

Comment: [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12925885/495132) to enable ENUM

Comment: Bit late, but Doctrine recommends tinyint for boolean types with mysql(http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix). You could convert the  bit columns to tinyint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your own, custom type for Doctrine.

1. Create a new type by extending `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type` class.
2. Override `convertToPHPValue()` and `convertToDatabaseValue()` methods.
3. Register a new type:

   ```
   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType('abc', 'Your\\Custom\\Type\\AbcType');

   $dbPlatform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
   $dbPlatform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('abc', 'abc');
   ```

Read more on Doctrine's [documentation pages](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)

Comment: can you please suggest from where I should execute that code (from command prompt? I'm on windows): $dbPlatform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$dbPlatform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('abc', 'abc');

Comment: It should be in some sort of application's bootstrap/db configuration file where you have access to `DatabasePlatform`.

Answer (score 38):

Use mapping_types in the config.yml

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: %% database_driver
        host: %% database_host
        port: %% database_port
        dbname: % database_name%
        user: %% database_user
        password: %% database_password
        charset: UTF8
        mapping_types:
            bit: boolean
```

Comment: It can work as a quick fix, but `bit` type is something else than a boolean. So watch out you may loose some information there.

Answer (score 12):

In case you are using `BIT` column to store a `boolean`, you do this:

```
// get currently used platform
$dbPlatform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();

// interpret BIT as boolean
$dbPlatform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('bit', 'boolean');
```

Now every time you map a property to bit column, doctrine 2 will interpret its value as a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following steps to solve this problem:

1. Open the File at the following Location like in linux scenario the path is: `var\www\html\admin\libraries\Composer\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform.php`
2. Go to this Function `initializeDoctrineTypeMappings()`
3. Now simply add the entry of your mapping like in my case I mapped bit with Boolean as given below:

   ```
   'bit' => 'boolean',
   ```
4. Reload your App and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an integer instead, or a bit string (though this doesn't allow you to to bit operations on it).

Here's a full example:

```php
namespace App\Type;    
    
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;    
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;    
    
class BitType extends Type {

    public const BIT = "bit";

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return self::BIT;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        if(is_null($value)){
            return $value;
        }
        return (int)$value; // alt. return decbin( $value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        if(is_null($value)){
            return $value;
        }
        return (int)$value; // alt. return bindec( $value);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return static::BIT;
    }
}
```

Then register it in `doctrine.yaml` like this:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # [...] other configs here
        types:
          bit: App\Type\BitType
        mapping_types:
          bit: bit
```