# Laravel 5.4 migration ENUM fails in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

when I try to apply my migration, I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.
```

The migration is applied, enum column is created on database and I get the error, so I can't execute the nexts migrations because this migration throw this error.

In the server, I've MySQL version 5.7.17

This is the code of my migration:

```
class AddDocumentUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('document', 9)->unique();
            $table->enum('document_type', ['dni', 'nie', 'nif', 'cif']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('document');
            $table->dropColumn('document_type');
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Reading laravel documentation, I see: _"The following column types can not be "changed": char, double, enum, mediumInteger, timestamp, tinyInteger, ipAddress, json, jsonb, macAddress, mediumIncrements, morphs, nullableMorphs, nullableTimestamps, softDeletes, timeTz, timestampTz, timestamps, timestampsTz, unsignedMediumInteger, unsignedTinyInteger, uuid."_ But I'm not trying alter column, I'm trying create it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Information related strictly to laravel can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1186). I highly advise you read the thread. This is NOT a laravel issue, it's been a bug in Doctrine since forever.

From the issue thread above, user `henritoivar` has an interesting idea.

Quoting here:

> This worked for me in laravel 5.2 with doctrine/dbal@^2.5 . When you
>   have an enum on your table and you want to change any of the columns
>   on the table you will have to:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

    Schema::table('jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->decimal('latitude', 10, 6)->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

I have no idea if this will work for you, but it's worth a try.

---

I would have posted this as a comment, but it's a damn long read.

[From the official Doctrine documents](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html):

> The type system of Doctrine 2 consists of flyweights, which means
>   there is only one instance of any given type. Additionally types do
>   not contain state. Both assumptions make it rather complicated to work
>   with the Enum Type of MySQL that is used quite a lot by developers.
>   When using Enums with a non-tweaked Doctrine 2 application you will get errors from the Schema-Tool commands due to the unknown
>   database type “enum”. By default Doctrine does not map the MySQL enum
>   type to a Doctrine type. This is because Enums contain state (their
>   allowed values) and Doctrine types don’t.

Technically speaking this can be solved. See [here](http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/09/deal-with-mysql-types-natively.html). But that relates strictly to symfony, on which Laravel is based.

---

[Laravel's docs also stated that it has a problem with `enums`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns):

> Renaming any column in a table that also has a column of type enum is >not currently supported.

---

While this is not an answer, I hope it points you in the right direction or at least gives you an idea of what you're facing.

---

More related questions:

[How to enable ENUMs in Symfony 2 / Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312271/how-to-enable-enums-in-symfony-2-doctrine)

[Laravel 5.1 Unknown database type enum requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140860/laravel-5-1-unknown-database-type-enum-requested)

Answer (score 3):

In the migration file that contains the ENUM type add a constructor method with the following:

```php
public function __construct() {
    // Register ENUM type
    DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```

This worked for me in Laravel 5.2. You could try add this at a higher level but this was a quicker for me :)